# Java 8: How to write lambda stream to work with JsonArray?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm very new to Java 8 lambdas and stuff... I want to write a lambda function that takes a `JSONArray`, goes over its `JSONObject`s and creates a list of values of certain field.

For example, a function that takes the `JSONArray`: `[{name: "John"}, {name: "David"}]` and returns a list of `["John", "David"]`.

I wrote the following code:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        jsonArray.add(new JSONObject().put("name", "John"));
        jsonArray.add(new JSONObject().put("name", "David"));
        List list = (List) jsonArray.stream().map(json -> json.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

However, I get an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

DO you know how to resolve it?

Comment: `put()` returns previous *value* by that name, which means `null` in your case. `put()` is not a [chaining method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JSONArray](http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/JSONArray.html) is a sub-class of `java.util.ArrayList` and [JSONObject](http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/JSONObject.html) is a sub-class of `java.util.HashMap`.

Therefore, `new JSONObject().put("name", "John")` returns the previous value  associated with the key (`null`), not the `JSONObject` instance. As a result, `null` is added to the `JSONArray`.

This, on the other hand, works:

```
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject j1 = new JSONObject();
    j1.put ("name", "John");
    JSONObject j2 = new JSONObject();
    j2.put ("name", "David");
    jsonArray.add(j1);
    jsonArray.add(j2);
    Stream<String> ss = jsonArray.stream().map (json->json.toString ());
    List<String> list = ss.collect (Collectors.toList ());
    System.out.println(list);
```

For some reason I had to split the stream pipeline into two steps, because otherwise the compiler doesn't recognize that `.collect (Collectors.toList())` returns a `List`.

The output is:

```
[{"name":"John"}, {"name":"David"}]
```

Comment: Raw `ArrayList` and `HashMap` are why the `stream()` pipeline didn't compile.

Comment: I assumed it had something to do with `JSONArray` extending a raw `ArrayList`, but I thought that after `.map (json->json.toString ())` the compiler could realize that the result must be a `Stream<String>`, regardless of the type of elements in the original raw `Stream`.

Comment: I guess it _could_, but `map` is erased immediately from its invocation on the raw `Stream`.

Comment: This wouldn't work with the org.json.jsonarray type unless you specifically cast from json-simple jsonarray.

Answer (score 24):

Try with IntStream.

```
List<String> jsonObject = IntStream
       .range(0,jsonArray.size())
       .mapToObj(i -> jsonArray.getJSONObject(i))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Method getJSONObject throws JSONException, thus the 3d line of your code is not valid because it should include a try-catch block.

Comment: I used this solution and works. @George siggouroglou  can you recheck. your comment , it is misleading, even if it thorows , you write throwing function . AFAIK, I like this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        jsonArray.add(new JSONObject().put("name", "John"));
        jsonArray.add(new JSONObject().put("name", "David"));
        List list = (List) jsonArray.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).map(json -> json.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

I have added `filter(Objects::nonNull)`, you can try this instead.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, I recognized that result of put is being added to json array instead of json object. Should be like this.

```
private static JSONObject getJson(String key, String value){
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
    result.put(key, value);
    return result;        
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    jsonArray.add(getJson("name", "John"));
    jsonArray.add(getJson("name", "David"));

    List list = (List) jsonArray.stream()
                .map(json -> json.toString())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

and output is now [{"name":"John"}, {"name":"David"}] like expected