# Unable to stream JSON array

Tags: java, json

**Below is my code:**

Imports are: org.json.JSONArray, org.json.JSONObject

```
String x="{\"count\":25,\"rows\":[{\"id\":10,\"name\":\"xxx\"},{\"id\":11,\"name\":\"xyx\"}]}";
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(x);
JSONArray arr=obj.getJSONArray("rows");
```

Actual data has many records with many key values which i need to filter. So i tried `arr.stream()` but on compilation itself it shows method `stream()` is undefined for type `JSONArray`.

I use java 8. streams work for list. I am getting values of key rows in arr. Please clarify why and how it can be solved.

Comment: The online sources I've found indicate that `JSONArray` doesn't implement any of the collection interfaces. What makes you think you could call `stream()` on it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595433/java-8-how-to-write-lambda-stream-to-work-with-jsonarray

Comment: Have a look at the packages. You're using `org.json.JSONArray` while the link you posted is about `org.json.simple.JSONArray` - note the `simple` package, that means a totally different library. That looks like the source for the class you are using: http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/json/JSONArray.html

Answer (score 6):

Well basically `org.json.JSONArray` is not array as such. It's just a class that represents JSON array (yep, sounds weird) which is `[]`.

Good news is that it implements `Iterable`. So you can get a stream like that:

```
String x="{\"count\":25,\"rows\":[{\"id\":10,\"name\":\"xxx\"},
{\"id\":11,\"name\":\"xyx\"}]}";

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(x);
JSONArray arr= obj.getJSONArray("rows");

StreamSupport.stream(arr.spliterator(), false)
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Out:

```
{"name":"xxx","id":10}
{"name":"xyx","id":11}
```

**Edit 1 - answer to comments**

Code that you provided works perfectly fine for me. It does filter all objects in array except those which have `id==11`:

```
List<JSONObject> list = StreamSupport.stream(arr.spliterator(), false)
            .map(val -> (JSONObject) val)
            .filter(val -> val.getInt("id") == 11)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(list);
```

Out:

```
[{"name":"xyx","id":11}]
```

Comment: Can you please even more help with how to filter and collect based on id, say, fetch values from rows where id=11

Comment: I tried like:
JSONArray cdvalues= StreamSupport.stream(arrs.spliterator(), false).map(val->(JSONObject)val).filter(val -> val.getInt("id")==11).collect(Collectors.toList());

I am not sure how to collect and i most times get cannot cast List<JSONObject> to JSONArray. if i cast to list<JSONObject> , it throws "JSONArray initial value should be a string or collection or array."

Comment: @Gayathri, pls see answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iterator to stream conversion:

```
Stream<String> stream= StreamSupport.stream(
                  arr.spliteratorUnknownSize(list.iterator(), Spliterator.ORDERED),
                  false);
```

Another solution would be to use the standard for java implementation - `javax.json.JsonArray` which is basically a collection and gives you a stream() method