# map() with JSON array

Tags: java, json, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

**Not Looking for Jackson Solution.**

> List of Imports:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
```

**JSON data:**

```
{
    "Name": "ABC.com",
    "Developer": "Vishwa ratna",
    "Project List": [
        "Compnay: National",
        "Compnay: Enterprise",
        "Compnay: Alamo"
    ]
}
```

**My program:**

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public  static  void main(String[] args)
    {
        File text = new File("R:/TestJSON.txt");
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("R:\\Desktop\\TestJSON.txt"));
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            String name = (String) jsonObject.get("Name");
            System.out.println(name);
            String author = (String) jsonObject.get("Developer");
            System.out.println(author);
            JSONArray companyList = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Project List");
            companyList.stream().map(e->{if(e.equals("Compnay: National")); return e;}).collect(Collectors.toList());
            list.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {}
    }
}
```

Everything is executing correctly except

```
companyList.stream().map(e->{if(e.equals("Compnay: National")); return e;}).collect(Collectors.toList());
            list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

I can get the desired result another way around but i want to know why my map is not returning anything?? should it not return `Compnay: National`.

Result i am getting:

```
ABC.com
Vishwa ratna
```

I am expecting:

```
ABC.com
Vishwa ratna
Compnay: National
```

**Edit:** Even after using `filter()` as suggested by some people here i am unable to get the desired result.

Comment: `map` is not very appropriate to use in your use case (filtering on '`Compnay: National`'. You want to use `filter` instead: `.filter(e -> e.equals("Compnay: National"))`.

Comment: No, filter will filter the collection on the predicate you specify. So all items that do not equals `Compnay: National` will not be included. You can then collect that result.

Comment: If I read that code correct, you are currently performing no operation  for `if (e.equals("Company: National")) ;` Its just an empty check within the `map`.

Comment: Read the documentation on filter: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-

Comment: @nullpointer, i am still not able to get result even after filter, just try at your side.

Comment: @CommonMan: `if(e.equals("Compnay: National"));` Observe the additional `;`  which roughly translates to *do nothing* when *your* if-statement is evaluated to true.

Comment: @NicholasK, i got the `;` point, but why still the filter is not filtering my result, am i missing anything??

Comment: @CommonMan: Post the code you have tried using *filter*

Comment: @NicholasK `list = companyList.stream()
           .filter(e-> e.equals("Compnay: National"))
           .map(Object::toString)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Nothing wrong with your *filter*. Can you paste the original contents of `companyList`?

Comment: `"Project List": [
        "Compnay: National",
        "Compnay: Enterprise",
        "Compnay: Alamo"
    ]`

Comment: Try this : `list = companyList.stream().map(json->json.toString()).filter(e-> e.equals("Compnay: National")).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: More info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595433/java-8-how-to-write-lambda-stream-to-work-with-jsonarray)

Comment: My whole library is : `import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;`

Comment: Did you tried my answers? Just copy-past them both work fine

Comment: I am not unto for getting the solution with Jackson or whatever. I guess you have tried with Map and filter and still there were errors as the Json was not getting parsed

Comment: @YCF_L, thats works perfectly fine :)

Comment: Listen, I don't suggest any thing that is not working, I test all my codes befor I put them in my answers, beside the solution with jakson is my favorite one, I use it for years

Comment: I appreciate it sir, Jackson is pretty powerful, i know it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **One** you have to use `filter` instead of `map`.
- **Second** you have to assign the result of collect to `list`

Your code should be :

```
   list = (List<String>) companyList.stream()
           .filter(e-> e.equals("Compnay: National"))
           .map(Object::toString)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Another solution maybe is to after the filter collect toArray, thenyou convert the array to stream use map with Object::toString then collect to list, this can work also

```
 list = Arrays.stream(
            companyList.stream()
                 .filter(e -> e.equals("Compnay: National"))
                 .toArray())
           .map(Object::toString)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

### Why filter and not map

`map` alwayse return a result, so if you make a condition inside `map` you have to use `else` part, it works in your case because you have a typo, your condition not make any sinse, but why you use if inside a `map`, and you have `filter` where you can avoid conditions?

```
Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate)
```

Like you see `filter` took a **predicate** and **return a new stream** not a **boolean** like you said in your comment

Comment: You should use map when you want to transform a collection into a different form. That is not appropriate here. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-

Comment: still, it doesnot work for me, `Incompatible types.
Required:
java.util.List
<java.lang.String>
Found:
java.lang.Object
`

Comment: return of a predicate is always a boolean, i.e `true or false`.

Comment: @CommonMan your filter return an Object so you have to use map with toString after filter, check my edit please, for for latness i'm using my phone

Comment: still, incompatible types i am getting.

Comment: `(List<String>)` should resolve the problem, I don't know what happen exactly with JSon, when I'm using my laptop, I will search more @Common Man

Comment: @YCF_L Given the use of `.map(Object::toString)`, the cast to `List<String>` should not be required.

Comment: @CommonMan I think what could also be misleading here is th use of `JSONArray` which might not be using the type of `List` interface while exposing the `stream` API. Please update the question with the library in use and the fully qualified name for `JSONArray`

Comment: @nullpointer may be you are right brother, still i am struck here.

Comment: @nullpointer yes it seems, but in fact I test it without casting and it not working, I don't understand what happen exactly, so with casting it work fine, I'm not using my pc, I will dig search more

Comment: @CommonMan I test the two solution and it works fine, can you please share your libraries please?

Answer (score 1):

### Another solution using Jackson library

I'm not sure what library you are using to parse your Json file, but, it seems not the perfect way, I would suggest another solution using [`jackson`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.9.8) library, so you have :

1- add to pom.xml the dependency :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

2- create a Job which is similar to your Json file like so :

```
class MyObject {

    private String name;
    private String developer;
    private List<String> projectList;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonSetter("Name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDeveloper() {
        return developer;
    }

    @JsonSetter("Developer")
    public void setDeveloper(String developer) {
        this.developer = developer;
    }

    public List<String> getProjectList() {
        return projectList;
    }

    @JsonSetter("Project List")
    public void setProjectList(List<String> projectList) {
        this.projectList = projectList;
    }
}
```

3- your code to parse

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Mcve {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String path = "R:\\Desktop\\TestJSON.txt";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
        MyObject obj = mapper.readValue(new File(path), MyObject.class);

        String name = obj.getName();
        System.out.println(name);
        String author = obj.getDeveloper();
        System.out.println(author);

        List<String> list = obj.getProjectList()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.equals("Compnay: National"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        list.forEach(System.out::println);

    }
}
```

**Outputs**

```
ABC.com
Vishwa ratna
Compnay: National
```

as you see, working with Objects is more easier and more helpful.

Comment: I like it, but is irrelevant here as i am not looking for Jackson soln here, BTW +1  for your efforts.